# Timed Webcam Capture Program Win7

Tags: images, automation, webcam, high-definition, timer

I have a couple of webcams and I want to be able to automatically capture an HD image from at least one of them every X minutes and just put them into a folder of my choosing. I don't want any timelapse features and I don't want to pay. I found the Powertoy Timershot, but it is WinXP only, and as I am running Win7 that won't work for me (Tried compatibility mode).

Comment: There  [**TinCam**](http://www.tincam.com/) can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [Yawcam](http://www.yawcam.com/index.php) before and from memory it allows you to do this. I only had a small play around after downloading but it also allows for a motion sensor and other random surveillance type features.

In terms of multiple camera's, if Yawcam doesn't support two camera's from one instance, I would imagine opening two instances would fix this issue. (I cannot test this as I only own one camera unfortunately).